# using mysql commands in sublime with xiki

Tags: mysql, sublimetext2, sublimetext, xiki

How to use mysql commands in sublime using xiki. 
I have tried but it does not allow me to login...
Here my username is "root" and password is "mysql".

```
$ mysql
  ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'owaishanif786'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

$$ mysql
  ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'owaishanif786'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

$$ mysql -u root -p

$$ mysql
  ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'owaishanif786'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

$$ mysql -u root -p mysql

$$ mysql
  ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'owaishanif786'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

$$
```

Comment: well it says that the password is NO so maybe make sure you have the correct credentials set up in the request.

Comment: May be your password is not correct.